# diff - find specific change between two values in hex dump

Tags: vim, hex, diff, vimdiff, xxd

I am analyzing hex data from binary data dumps from a basic command-line program of mine. I'm basically dumping the exact contents of a struct (a large array of structs, actually) to a text file.

I then create a second binary dump, and compare the two files in `vim` using `xxd` to create binary-to-text representations of the original data.

Both files are the exact same size in bytes, and I'm trying to compare the two in a meaningful way. Even a small change in the data before I dump the file results in a large change in other parts of the file, due to other sections containing hashes, functions based on the value I changed, and so forth.

Is it possible to tell `diff` or `vimdiff` to say, compare two files, and show me only the parts of the file where in the original file (ie: file 1) a value was set to `1`, and in the second file, the value was set to `32`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use:

```
diff <(xxd file1.bin) <(xxd file2.bin)
```

This uses [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to compare the output of two `xxd` processes.  Note that this still shows line differences, so if any byte on a line is different it will be listed. This gives a nice hexdump-looking comparison.

The classical tool for this however, is [`cmp`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_cmp.htm).

So, this could be handled like so:

```
cmp -l file1.raw file2.raw | grep -in "oldValue" | grep -in "newValue"
```

This will list exactly what you need, with the following fields printed out:

```
OFFSET  VALUE_IN_FILE_1 VALUE_IN_FILE_2
```

Comment: That offers a text-mode comparison of the output of two binary-to-text files, which I'm already generating in `vim`. How does this address the problem of field-specific comparison given that I know that a single field will start at value `x` and in the second file will be value `y`?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. `cmp -l`  will "Print the byte number (decimal) and the differing byte values (octal) for each difference."  Just `grep` through that list for the known values, and it will give you the decimal offset.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: a slight variation may be:  vim -d <(xxd fileA) <(xxd fileB)